# Regarding this integral function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, continuity, improper-integrals

I'm currently stuck with this problem:

Let $g:(a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that the improper integral $\int_a^b|g(x)|dx$ exists. Prove that:

$$G:(a,b]\to \mathbb{R} $$
$$r\mapsto\int_r^b|g(x)|dx$$

Extends to a continuous function $G:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $G(a)=\int_a^b|g(x)|dx$

I don't quite follow where to begin; my first attempt is to try and utilize the definition of continuity and see where to go from there. If that's correct can you give a hint how to begin writing the proof? Should I use the continuity on the limits of the integral? If is that so, how can does one do it? Those are the main questions that I'm struggling with, and that's the main reason I don't know where to begin.

I'll write down the definition I have for improper integral according to this problem:

Let $g:(a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that is a continuous function, the improper integral is:

$$\int_a^bg(x)dx=\lim_{r\to a}\int_r^bg(x)dx$$

Any hints will be appreciated, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

If you write
$$
\int_r^bg(x)dx=\int_a^b1_{[r,b]}(x)g(x)dx
$$
where $1_A$ denotes the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of a set $A$,
your limit follows from the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help I have for the moment, one question: Should I try to use the definition of continuity on that limit? How does the limit follow from that theorem? I haven't seen the limit like that. I'll read a little bit more and try to follow it.

Comment: @JoseCharly: you are welcome. Note that for every $x\in[a,b]$, $\lim_{r\to a}1_{[r,b]}(x)g(x)\to g(x)$. Because $\int_{a}^b|g(x)|dx<\infty$, and $|1_{[r,b]}(x)g(x)|\le |g(x)|$, you can apply the dominated convergence theorem.